# Bring Local Git Branch and github Fork up to date with upstream

Tags: git, github

Okay this has been annoying me for a while and I seem to have tried just about every possible command and can't figure it out (I'm fairly new to git).

Here's what happened:
working in my local repo (A) while a friend makes commits to the main upstream repo (U). Forget to pull his changes from U and push A to my fork on github (B).  Now B is 3 commits ahead of U, but also 7 commits behind (that just seems bad to be both ahead and behind).

What I tried Next:
fetching and reseting my local to try to match U.  Now if I do "git pull U" I get the following:

- branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD

Already up-to-date.

which seems good?

However, if I then try to push this to my fork B on github:

git push url(B)

! [rejected]        U -> U (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to "url(B)"
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
counterpart.

Ugh Idk what to do at this point since it seems like my local matches the upstream, but I can't push to my fork on github to make it match the upstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do.  If, from your local repo (A), you rebased your 3 changes on top of your friends 7 changes, then you should use the 'force' option to 'git push' to force the update to occur.

```
git push -f url(b)
```

Note that if other people may have cloned repository B this can cause problems for them, so use with caution.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up doing a merge with strategy theirs, which just threw out my conflicting files resolving the merge conflicts.